# Symfony unserialize error on a php 7.4 environment

Tags: php, session, symfony4

We have 2 applications on a different subdomain, sharing the same session. One application is Symfony 3.4 latest, the other one Symfony 4.4 latest. So far, no issues.

We upgraded or test environment from php 7.3.5 to php 7.4.11 and authenticated sessions got lost after passing the app with Symfony 4.4.

The Symfony 3.4 fails silently on unserialize and populates tokenStorage with an anonymous token.

Dump of the logged Symfony 3.4 exception:

```
{
    "message": "Failed to unserialize the security token from the session.",
    "context": {
        "key": "_security_secured_area",
        "received": "O:67:\"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Guard\\Token\\PostAuthenticationGuardToken\":....}",
        "exception": {
            "class": "UnexpectedValueException",
            "message": "Erroneous data format for unserializing 'Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Guard\\Token\\PostAuthenticationGuardToken'",
            "code": 57873340,
            "file": "/var/www/.../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ContextListener.php:250"
        }
    },
    "level": 300,
    "level_name": "WARNING",
    "channel": "security",
}
```

We've never seen this exception before and we have no clue how to start debugging this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up by upgrading the Symfony 3.4 application to Symfony 4 latest.